# In parametric equation $x = x(t)$, $y = y(t)$, what does $y(x)$ describe?

Tags: calculus, parametric

When I eliminate a parameter from the parametric equation and receive $y = y(x)$, what does $y$ actually describe? I know that $y$ describes the shape of the parametric equation ONLY, not speed or direction.
In case when $x = x(t)$, $y = y(t)$ has a complicated shape can we actually get the same shape for $y(x)$?
For example:
let$$x = 2\sin(1+3t)$$
and
$$y = 2t^3$$
eliminating the parameter *t* I receive:
$$y = 2\left(\frac{\arcsin(\frac{x}{2}) - 1}{3}\right)^3$$
and its graph is just a little part of the graph of the parametric equation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Q. "what does $y$ describe ?" A. The same as before just as a function of $x$ instead of $t\,.$  In your example there is no one-to-one map from $t$ to $x\,.$ Think about this.

Comment: @KurtG. can you describe in more detail please?

Comment: Have you given some thoughts to the obvious fact that the range of $t$ is $\mathbb R$ but the range of $x$ is only $[-2,2]\,?$ You simply don't have a map $x\mapsto t,[-2,2]\to\mathbb R$ that is surjective because $x$ is a periodic function of $t\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. oh indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @KurtG. can you post the answer so I will close the topic?

Comment: @KurtG. now the thing I don't understand is dy/dx = dy/dt/dx/dt, so for example if I choose t = 1, dy/dt = 6, dx/dt ≈ -3.9216. dy/dt/dx/dt ≈ -1.53. And there is no x for which dy/dt would have this value.

Comment: What a mess. The chain rule says
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}(t(x))=\frac{dy}{dt}(t(x))\frac{dt}{dx}(x)
$$
Is there an $x$ for which $t(x)=1\,?$ Plot that function and you'll see.

Comment: @KurtG. why do you use t(x)? I took the formula from Stewart's Calculus.

Comment: Mathematics is not performed by "taking formulas" without knowing what we are doing. If we believe in the chain rule we have to compose the functions $x\mapsto t$ and $t\mapsto y$ and take the derivative w.r.t. $x$ of the composition.

Comment: @KurtG. And Chain rule gives $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$$. I still don't get why you need t(x) for any of these derivatives.

Comment: That's another chain rule. Not the one that was  behind that Stewart Calculus formula you used: $(dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$ and which you wanted to be $\approx -1.53\,.$ Written properly that Stewart formula gives  on the left hand side  $dy/\color{red}{dx}\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. It is. Stewart wrote : "if dx/dt != 0, we can solve for dy/dx:"               $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

Comment: I did not see you solving for $dy/dx$ because of my comment made earlier. Again: is there an $x$ for which you can assume (as you did) $t(x)=1\,?$ Have you plotted that function by now?

Comment: @KurtG. I'm not sure what do you mean. I have a function x(t) = 2sin(1+3t). For t = 1 it has a value ≈ 1.5136 . The same will be if I will have t(x), for x ≈ 1.5136 t will be ≈ 1.

Comment: I'm not sure how you do those calculations. For $t=1$ I get $x\approx\color{red}{-}1.5136\,.$ Last hint: Can you think of other $t$'s that give you the same $x\,?$ (We talked about that, and 7h ago you wrote "oh indeed thanks".) ***Case closed***

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry to bother you, you are correct x ≈−1.5136. I understand that x ≈−1.5136 for many t's.  But that's what I'm asking, why $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$\ but in my case dy/dx does not exist for the point where t = 1, so dy/dx can't be used to determine the angle of tangent line to the parametric equation.

Comment: The answer to the question that you ask first is that locally you can find $y(x)$ such that $(x,y(x))$ has the same shape as $(x(t), y(t))$ as long as $(x'(t), y'(t)) \neq (0,0)$. As you see with your example, there is no guarantee this can be done for the entire curve, but at any point $(x(t), y(t))$ where the speed is not $0$ we are sure to be able to find a function whose graph is the same as the curve. This is known as the implicit function theorem.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins so there is no guarantee that derivative of y(x) will cover all derivatives of parametric equations, right?

Comment: That's not what I said. Every parametric curve locally (on a small interval) has the same shape as the graph of a function anywhere where its speed is not $0$. But we are generally not able to find a single function that has the same shape as a parametric curve. For example, the parametric curve which traces a unit circle at unit speed will not be the graph of any single function (think about the vertical line test). But $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ has the same shape as the top half of the circle and $y = -\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ has the same shape as the bottom half of the circle.

Comment: I was also trying to simplify things slightly, so what I said isn't exactly true. The more precise statement is that if $x'(t) \neq 0$, then there locally exists a function $y(x)$ so that $(x, y(x))$ traces the same curve as $(x(t), y(t))$. Likewise, if $y'(t) \neq 0$, then there locally exists a function $x(y)$ so that $(x(y), y)$ traces the same curve as $(x(t), y(t))$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins and that exactly what I'm trying to understand. That for complex graph's(which don't pass vertical line test) we can't rely on single y(x) since it won't cover all curves of the graph. As in my example y(x) is covering only a small part of parametric equations and some angles of tangent lines to parametric equations can't even exist for y(x), is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

The [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of $\arcsin$ has range $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\,.$ When $t=1$ your $1+3t$ is outside of that range. If you take another branch of $\arcsin$ (by flipping its sign and adding $\pi$ to the principal value) whose range contains $1+3t=4$ you should be able to find $dy/dx$ with that method:

> \begin{align}t&=\frac{-\arcsin(x/2)+\pi-1}{3}\,,&y&=2t^3\,,&\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{-6t^2}{3\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,.\end{align}